# Whitespace errors in JavaSCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, dom, whitespace

I' am practicing with HTML DOM, and I' am trying to figure out why first script works and displays childNodes; but the second script doesn't.

```
<html><head><title>The Nodes</title>
<style>
p{font-size: x-large; color:darkblue;font-style:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Walking with Nodes</h1>
<p>Who knows what node?</p>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Parent=document.childNodes[0];  // First childnode is HTML
var Child=Parent.childNodes[0];// Parent’s first child is HEAD

document.write("The parent node is: ");
document.write(Parent.nodeName+"<br />"); //Get the name parent node
document.write("The first child of the parent node is: ");
document.write(Child.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The node below the child is: ");
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The text node below title is: ");
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeName +"<br />");
document.write("The value of the text node is: ")
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"<br/>");
document.write("The first child of the parent is: ");
document.write(Parent.firstChild.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The last child of the parent is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The node below the body is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The next sibling of the h1 element is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nextSibling.nodeName+"<br/>");
document.write("It's value is " +
Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nextSibling.nodeValue);
document.write("<br>The last child's type is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.nodeType);
</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the code above runs properly; but the one below doesn't and I tried debugging it via firebug; but i get nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>the Nodes</title>
<style type="text/css">
p {
font-size: x-large;color:darkblue;font-style:bold;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Practicing with nodes</h1>
<p>Who knows what node?</p>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Parent = document.childNodes[0]; // documents child is HTML
var Child = Parent.childNodes[0]; // first child node of HTML is head 

document.write("The parent node is: ");
document.write(Parent.nodeName+"<br>");
document.write("The first child of the parent node is: ");
document.write(Child.nodeName+"<br>");
document.write("The parent node is: ");
document.write(Parent.nodeName+"<br />"); //Get the name parent node
document.write("The first child of the parent node is: ");
document.write(Child.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The node below the child is: ");
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The text node below title is: ");
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeName +"<br />");
document.write("The value of the text node is: ")
document.write(Child.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"<br/>");
document.write("The first child of the parent is: ");
document.write(Parent.firstChild.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The last child of the parent is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The node below the body is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nodeName+"<br />");
document.write("The next sibling of the h1 element is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nextSibling.nodeName+"<br/>");
document.write("It's value is " +
Parent.lastChild.childNodes[0].nextSibling.nodeValue);
document.write("<br>The last child's type is: ");
document.write(Parent.lastChild.nodeType);

//]]>
</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain me to what I' m doing wrong, and what would whitespace bug have to do with above script. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: `Parent.childNodes[0]` is undefined. In the other words, `Parent.childNodes.length` is equal to "0"

Comment: Why are you using doucument.write()?

Comment: Can you emphasize what the difference is between the top and bottom code?  I cannot tell what is different.  All I see is a massive amount of `document.write()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the DOCTYPE, then the first element is not "HTML tag", `document.childNodes[0]` returns the DOCTYPE and not the HTML.

`Parent.nodeName` returns the HTML string. Because it means that the document type is HTML.

Use `document.documentElement`, see example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Parent = document.documentElement; // documents child is HTML
var Child = Parent.childNodes[0]; // first child node of HTML is head
```

Or use `getElementsByTagName`, see example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Parent = (document.getElementsByTagName("html"))[0]; // documents child is HTML
var Child = Parent.childNodes[0]; // first child node of HTML is head
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude, I get it now. I now will be able to use HTML DOM in my websites now without worry.

Comment: also just curious, but why put the underscore before Parent.childNodes[0];

Comment: It was a typo. Please accepted my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `document.childNodes[0]` is `<html>` and this node has the child `<head>`.

In the second example `document.childNodes[0]` is `<!DOCTYPE html>` and this node does not have children. So `Parent.childNodes[0]` is undefined and causes a javascript error.

Comment: thanks. I see why whenever i removed "<!DOCTYPE html>" it would work.